# Join different DataFrames using loop in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 5 CSV files in a file, and want to join them in one data frame in Pyspark: I use the **code below**:

```
name_file =['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'V']
for n in name_file:
n= spark.read.csv(fullpath+n+'.csv'
                ,header=False, 
                inferSchema= True)
full_data=full_data.join(n,["id"])
```

**Error**: I  got an unexpected result > The last dataframe joined just with itself.

**Expected Result**: There should be 6 columns, each CSV has 2 data frames one of them in common with others. The join should be on this column. As a result, the final data frame should have a common column and 5 special columns from each CSV file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be several things wrong with the code or perhaps you have not provided the complete code.

1. Have you defined fullpath?
2. You have set header=False then how will spark know that there is an
   "id" column?
3. Your indentation looks wrong under the for loop.
4. full_data has not been defined yet, so how are you using it on the
   right side of the evaluation within the for loop? I suspect you have
   initialized this to the first csv file and then attempting to join
   it with first csv again.

I ran a small test on the below code which worked for me and addresses the questions I've raised above. You can adjust it to your need.

```
fullpath = '/content/sample_data/'
full_data = spark.read.csv(fullpath+'Book1.csv'
                      ,header=True, 
                      inferSchema= True)
name_file =['Book2', 'Book3']
for n in name_file:
  n= spark.read.csv(fullpath+n+'.csv'
                      ,header=True, 
                      inferSchema= True)
  full_data=full_data.join(n,["id"])
full_data.show(5)
```

Comment: You get all three Book1, 2, and 3? I tried but in the end, full_data only has the last Book3.

Comment: Yes we get a merge of all 3 files joining with 1 column. Unless you put your code in, we are not really sure what you have tried and hence cannot help. You should check that your code matches what I've above including all indentations. Since this question is already answered and closed, suggest you raise a new question.